# Displaying JSON

Tags: json, ajax

I am returning JSON from my controller to AJAX success response. The JSON look likes:

```
{
   "success": false,
   "errors": {
      "ConfirmPassword": [
         "'Confirm Password' and 'Password' do not match.",
         "Password does not meet the criteria.",
         "The Confirm Password must be at least 6 characters long."
      ],
      "Password": [
         "Password does not meet the criteria.",
         "The Password must be at least 6 characters long."
      ]
   }
}
```

Now I wan to display data in div tag with formatting. I have tried :

> $('#info').append(JSON.stringify(data));

but this is just a dump of whole string, which doesn't look nice in my view. Any idea how to do it. 
Ajax call :

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Dashboard/UpdatePassword/',
            data: $("#password-update-form").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {

                    //alert("test");
                }
                else {



                    $('#info').append(JSON.stringify(data));

                }
```

Comment: Are you using any other web application frameworks, i.e. Ruby on Rails?  Doing this with straight JS on the front-end is doable, but there is probably an easier way.

Comment: No I am not using any other framework.

Comment: Your json can easily be accessed, using _data_ paramater, but first of all make sure you have put `dataType: "json"`, in your $.ajax() request.

Comment: Also how do you want the contents of this json to be shown in your div tag?

Comment: I just want to show like: <p>Confirm Password' and 'Password' do not match</p> . I tried dataType: "json" in my ajax request , still now data is shown in div. If I do console.log(data.errors); I can see the data in my console.Thansk

Comment: Also tried : 
 var htmlToEmbed
                    //console.log(data.errors)                   
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.errors.length; i++)
                        for (var keys in data.errors[i])
                            htmlToEmbed += data.errors[i][keys]
                     $('#info').html(htmlToEmbed);
still the div is shwoing no data.

Comment: Try JSON.parse() as demonstrated here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all replies. I managed to sorted it.

```
  success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {

                    alert("test");
                }
                else {


                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.errors))

                    for (var prop in data.errors) {
                        //alert(prop + " is " + data.errors[prop]);                      
                         $('#val-form').append('<p>'+data.errors[prop]+'<p>');

                    }
```